Migrating from Progress v11.xx to v12.xx and still supporting 32 ocx's
We are trying to migrate off of Progress V11 to V12 before the spring when v11 will no longer be supported.  Currently our application relies on several 32bit ocx's, and we have been told by Progress that we can migrate to V12 and still use these.  However, Progress is unable to tell us exactly how to get this to work.
We have been told to maintain our v11 development environment and then distribute the .wrx files to the version 12 environment that the v12 compiled code would work if the wrx from the v11.xx environment exists, this has proven to not be correct, at least for us.
Has anyone else out here migrated from a 32bit Progress environment to a 64 bit and still maintained the use of the ocx's?

Which OCX (Active X Controls)? Active X is available in general for 64 bit too - but most control vendors never migrated their components to 64 bit.

If dependent on Active X Controls, you can stick with 32 bit OpenEdge 12.

@MikeFechner we have been told that the 32-bit OpenEdge is only available with the 4GL Development System license.   Our clients only have a run-time version of OpenEdge version12 and this is only available in 64-bit.

There is definitely a 32-bit OpenEdge 12 WebClient - you've moved all your database access to the AppServer already right? ;-)

Client networking (the GUI runtime for fat client) is available 32 bit too! https://docs.progress.com/de-DE/bundle/OpenEdge-12-Platform-Compatibility-Guide/resource/OpenEdge-12-Platform-Compatibility-Guide.pdf

No AppServer used in the current architecture.
